# Troubleshooting Could not find installable ISAM error

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, isam

I have 32-bit MS Office 2013 Installed, along with the 32-bit office redistributable and a small c# console application set to compile to 32-bit.

The following code causes an `OleDbException` stating "Could not find installable ISAM."

```
public void GetData()
{
    var fileName = @"c:\temp\Sales DataBase_Test.accdb";
    var connection = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Soure='" + fileName + "'";
    using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connection))
    {
        conn.Open();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Instead of randomly applying solutions from a dozen vague answers, I'd like to know:

- what that actually means?
- What is an installable ISAM?
- How do I get a list of them?
- How do I know which are available?
- Finally, how do I know which Providers are available on any given machine?
- Is there a way to enumerate these things and properly troubleshoot?

Comment: That error usually appears when trying to open XL files or import/parse flat files with unknown extensions.  You could try a) get rid of the space in the file name - it might think "DataBase..." is the extension b) ConnectionStrimngBuilder c) look at `conn.ConnectionString` to see if it looks right.  (Assumes you are correct about 32bit everything)

Comment: I misspelled "Data Source" and spent hours searching for the wrong thing :(  Would still like to know the answers to my questions though.

Answer (score 1):

My issue turned out to be aging eyes and fat fingers:  "Data Source" was misspelled as "Data Soure".

This doesn't answer my questions, but may help someone else.  I generated a working connection string by linking the data in Excel and then copying and pasting and then removing what I didn't need.

1. Get data from access (pick any table).
   [image]
2. Next open connections.

   [image]
3. You can then look at the properties of the connection and copy a working connection string which you can paste into your code and edit.

   [image]